# .Net 6 Windows Forms with Blazor services.AddHttpContextAccessor();, httpcontext is null

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, blazor

I am trying to setup Blazor server Authentication system in a windows forms with Blazor app.

I add service services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); in my startup that I added many other services that work.But when I inject this service to a .razor file the service is null.

How to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

In general, I don't recommend using the `IHttpContextAccessor` anywhere, and it is not something that works with SignalR apps or Blazor apps for that matter. For more info, you can refer to [Blazor and shared state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-and-shared-state-1) and [Accessing HttpContext.Items fails](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17585).

However, if you have to use the `HttpContext` then you have to get the desired value(s) from `HttpContext` when rendering `_Host.cshtml` and save it in a variable and use that variable in the form of Cascading Parameters in the components in the rest of the program.

For example, I use the following procedure to get `HttpContext` in Blazor Server web application.

The working method is that I modify the `_Host.cshtml` file as follows firstly. Here I'm looking for access_token information.

```
@{
    var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");
}
```

As you can see, I put the access_token information into the token variable and assign it to the component's `param-AccessToken`.
Then I go to the `App.razor` file and define the `AccessToken` variable as a Cascading Value. As follows:

```
<CascadingValue Name="AccessToken" Value="AccessToken">
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

```
@code{
    [Parameter]
     public string AccessToken { get; set; }
 }
```

Finally, any components that need an `AccessToken` value just need to define it as a Cascade Parameter. For example, I create a component called `ShowToken.razor` and put its codes as below:

```
@page "/showtoken"

<p>This is part of the access token @(AccessToken != null ? AccessToken.Substring(0,30) : "(null)")</p>


@code {
    [CascadingParameter(Name = "AccessToken")] public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```